# Determine origin for called Custom Alexa Skill on an AWS Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

this is a hopefully a quick one. I've got a custom Alexa Smart Home skill that I've built using an AWS Lambda function. The skill works well, but I'd like this skill to be only accessible to one of my two Alexa devices. I've looked through the `request` header and I cannot find any device origin id, so the code below of course doesn't work. Seems like an oversight to not put this info in the `request` (`context` is no help either). Is there a way I can set up my Lambda function to know this info? Perhaps I need to pass more info from the Alexa Dev Console skill? Any help would be appreciated.

```
exports.handler = function(request, context) {
log("DEBUG:", "main: ", JSON.stringify(request));
  if(request.originDevice == "Alexa Pop 1" ) return
  ...
}
```

**CloudWatch Log**

```
{
    "directive": {
        "header": {
            "messageId": "b78206f8-3e64-4ef1-966c-ff1b33e48c05",
            "namespace": "Alexa.PowerController",
            "name": "TurnOff",
            "payloadVersion": "3",
            "correlationToken": "--"
        },
        "endpoint": {
            "scope": {
                "type": "BearerToken",
                "token": "---"
            },
            "endpointId": "all_lights",
            "cookie": {
                "id": "1"
            }
        },
        "payload": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user friendly name of the device which initiated the request isn't passed to your lambda.  There is a deviceId value but that varies each time you enable the skill.  You could find out the deviceId by inspecting the logs when you make a request from the specific Alexa device and use that in your Lambda.  But the value will change if you disable/reenable the skill.

request.Context.System.device.deviceId

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#system-object

Comment: that's strange, I don't see this parameter in the Lambda `request` json or passed to my skill endpoint when viewing my CloudWatch logs.

Comment: It will be in every request.  What are you outputing to the cloudwatch log ?

Comment: `exports.handler = function(request, context) { log("DEBUG:", "main: ", JSON.stringify(request));  }`

Comment: OK, are you not using the Alexa node SDK ?  And can you paste in the debug output you get from your logger so I can see what's being logged.

Comment: No, I guess not. I'm using Node 20.x Runtime in Lambda. I have just updated my question with the log result.

Comment: Ah, I see that's a request associated with a Smart Home skill.  I was assuming a normal custom skill.  No experience of Smart Home skills unfortunately.